# Using Unity to get objects based on name alone

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, unity-container

I have an app with a handler method.  The handler method gets a json string which includes the name of the object that needs to handle the request and the parameters for the request.  Basically, something (I'll keep it simple) like this:

```
public interface IJob
{
    bool Execute();
    bool Hydrate(string source);
}

public class JobBase 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public JobType JobType { get; set; }
    public CronExpression CronExpression { get; set; }
}

public class JobSubmitClone : JobBase, IJob
{
    public string[] Tokens { get; set; }

    public bool Hydrate(string source)
    {
        // code omitted...
        return true;
    }
    public bool Execute()
    {
        // code omitted...
        return true;
    }
}
```

IJob and JobBase are both kept in a Common class project.  All apps reference this DLL.

In my main app I have Unity installed and one of the steps in loading the container is accomplished like:

```
// Scan assemblies for Job definitions...
_container.RegisterTypes(AllClasses.FromAssembliesInBasePath().
    Where(type => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type)),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    WithName.TypeName,
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

Each "Job" is defined in its own class project and is **NOT** referenced by the main app.  Each "Job" **must** inherit from `JobBase` and `IJob`.

The main app has a simple REST service exposed.  You can post something like:

```
{ jobName : JobSubmitClone, Id : 1, JobType : 2, CronExpression : '' }
```

In the main app I am trying to pull the object from the container based on `JobName`.  I've tried this (yes, I know it violates the IoC pattern):

```
var container = UnityHelpers.GetConfiguredContainer();
var job = container.Resolve<IJob>(myParams.jobName);  // "JobSubmitClone" //
var hydrated = job.Hydrate(myParams);
if(hydrated)
    var result = job.Execute();
```

I am getting the following error:

> Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The current type, IJob, is
>   an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type
>   mapping?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that there are a lot of ways to manipulate Unity.  This is what ended up working so far:

```
container.RegisterTypes(
    AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies().Where(type => typeof(IJob).IsAssignableFrom(type) && type.IsClass),
    WithMappings.FromAllInterfaces,
    t => t.IsNested ? t.DeclaringType.Name + "." + t.Name : t.Name,
    WithLifetime.Transient);
```

I also built an extension method:

```
public static IJob Job(this string src)
{
    var container = UnityConfig.GetConfiguredContainer();
    var job = container.Resolve<IJob>(src);
    return job;
}
```

I created a small model for the Minimum Payload:

```
public class MinimumCommandModel : IRequest<MinimumResultModel>
{
    public MinimumCommandModel(string json)
    {
        FullPayloadString = json;
        MinimumPayload = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MinimumPayload>(json);
    }

    public string MinimumPayloadString => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(MinimumPayload); 
    public string FullPayloadString { get; set; }
    public MinimumPayload MinimumPayload { get; set; }
}
```

I can then directly get a job from a (JSON) sting payload:

```
var command = new MinimumCommandModel(Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
var job = command.MinimumPayload.JobName.Job();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Each "Job" is defined in its own class project and is NOT referenced
>   by the main app. Each "Job" must inherit from JobBase and IJob.

Have you looked into MEF? It has the ability to query and load a class by its metadata. I tend to use Unity for known, compile-time dependencies and MEF for dynamic assemblies loaded at runtime. (There's no reason you can't use both in the same project.)

We do something similar to what you're looking for, I think.  We load workflows based on their class name.

Just decorate the Job with a System.ComponentModel.Composition.MetadataAttribute....

```
[MetadataAttribute]
public class WorkflowMetadataAttribute : Attribute, IWorkflowMetadata 
{
    public WorkflowMetadataAttribute(string typeName) {
        TypeName = typename;
    }
    public string TypeName { get; private set; }
}
```

Which you put on the thing you want to export....

```
public interface IWorkflow // aka IJob
{
    void Execute();
}

[Export(typeof(IWorkflow))]
[WorkflowMetadata("WhateverWorkflow")]
public class WhateverWorkflow : IWorkflow 
{
    public void Execute() { }
}
```

The exported class can be built separately of the project that runs it. If you build it as a library into a separate assembly, you can load the assembly (or directory of assemblies) in an importer class.

```
public class WorkflowCatalog : IPartImportsSatisfiedNotification
{
    [ImportMany]
    public IEnumerable<Lazy<IWorkflow, IWorkflowMetadata>> Workflows { get; private set; }

    public void Compose() {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName( Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location );
        var catalog = new DirectoryCatalog( path );
        var compositionContainer = new CompositionContainer( catalog );
        compositionContainer.ComposeParts(this);
    }

    public void OnImportsSatisfied() {
        var workflow = Workflows.Single(w => w.Metadata.TypeName == "WhateverWorkflow").Value;
        workflow.Execute();
    }
}
```

IJob, IJobMetadata, and JobBase live in the core. Job classes live in their own libraries (or they can live in the main program too I suppose).